# What is the formula for maximum battery pulse vs pulse duration?

Tags: pulse, high-current, lithium, burst

I am interested in finding the maximum current a lithium-ion battery can provide for pulses in the order of 50 ms.

If my battery can provide 50 A continuously and 120 A for 10 seconds, how can I find, simulate, or extrapolate a 50 ms value? Internal impedance at 1 kHz is 6 mΩ.

Comment: Not from those two values. Find the resistance or short circuit current. 50 ms "feels" at the upper limit of not bothering about heating ***if*** the duty cycle is low *and* cell temperature not high to begin with.

Comment: Published internal impedance at 1khz is 6mΩ, would I just divide voltage by that value and say that's the maximum for 50 msec? Duty cycle is one shot every minute or so

Comment: @GregSorter Without an accurate battery model (and they aren't simple beasts -- either of us could google one up from a research paper given some moments of time) you can't really shift the goal posts by more than 2 orders of magnitude and get away with it. If interested as you say, then recommend designing a test to find out, getting out a logbook, buying 10 of these batteries, gather and log data over various operation temperatures, then interpreting them to complete your experimental results. Or, you could contact the manufacturer hoping they can help. They may. Or may not. No idea.

Comment: @GregSorter Also, since you've said nothing about your own interest here -- not a drop of application space concept to be had from you -- there's little by way of narrowing ideas about approaching your experimental setup that can be offered, I think.

Comment: I would definitely call the manufacturer if I could, but A123 Systems is no longer. I do have a LiFEpo4 battery model in LT Spice that works very well, incorporating SOC, inductance, capacitance, etc. But, that doesn't have any of the physical changes and/or damage that the battery would see. The A123 battery is relatively bulletproof. I am sizing an inductor for very short pulses, and believe in simulating as much as possible before building anything. Simply figuring how many turns I need and at the same time not destroying the battery